# django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied when migrating django app

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, psycopg2

I'm a beginner with Django working on an open source project, which has been very challenging since it only gives build instructions for Mac, and not Linux. So, on my Ubuntu server, I've managed to install all the packages and fix a few initial bugs, but now, when I do `python manage.py migrate`, I'm stuck with this error: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

I'm totally stuck here: I'm having a tough time understanding the error message, and other solutions aren't much help. Other solutions indicate that you have to change the DATABASES setting in the settings.py, but the setting has no PASSWORD attribute and it's only linked to sqlite:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

The error doesn't trace back to any specific lines of code so I'm guessing its more related to psycopg2 or django than the code itself, but I'm not sure how to go about fixing it. I'm using Python 2.7.17 and Ubuntu 18.04.5. Here's the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 83, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 210, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 254, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 229, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 213, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 189, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 176, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Again, I'm very new to Django and Postgres, so I may be missing something obvious. It's equally likely that the code just doesn't work on Linux or that there's some unfixed bug in it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are overriding the sqlite settings with `DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()`. So you must see this: https://github.com/jacobian/dj-database-url/blob/1937ed9e61d273163353c8546825dd529ce8546c/dj_database_url.py#L59 . So this makes your default setting to `{}`.

Comment: @VineetYadav thanks, I didn't recognize that as an external package. I ended up fixing it based off your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Vineet pointed out, the `DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()` line was overwriting the configuration, and as a result the 'PASSWORD' and other attributes existed and were blank. I added this line after it:

`del DATABASES['default']['PASSWORD'], DATABASES['default']['HOST'], DATABASES['default']['PORT']`

and the problem has been solved.